# Images resizing in outlook email template

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am creating html email template and i've got a problem, beacuse on SOME outlooks (not on every) some of my images are resizing (they are getting smaller). Width of image is 600, but in e-mail on outlook it's getting someting like 500.

It is mailing, so i'm doing it via tables

````
<td align="center" width="600"><img src="cantshowithere:("  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" alt="banner.png" title="banner.png" /></td>
</tr>```

How to solve this thing?
````

Comment: Why don't you give the image width: 600px?

Comment: Outlook doesn't respect "px"

Comment: It does. I've created many complex email templates for Outlook and for other email clients. Use inline style for the img.